# Reduced chi-sqaure and confidence interval

Tags: statistics

I asked a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351877/how-to-define-confidence-interval-for-reduced-chi-square-test) previously in another group but I did not get any response, can anyone from this group help me to solve this?

I have observed data and predicated data from different models. I did the reduced chi-square test between the observed and model data using the below equation:$$
\text{reduced } X^2 = \frac{1}{v} \sum\frac{(\text{obs-model})^2}{\sigma^2},
$$
where $v$ is the degree of freedom and $\sigma$ is the variance of the observed data.

I got the reduced chi-square value from $0$ to $500$, as we know that the reduced chi-square value no greater than $1$ indicates that the extent of the match between observations and estimates is in accord with the error variance. So we suggest the models which are within $0$-$1$ reduced chi-square value.

But I want to defined the confidence interval for the reduced chi-square. I want to find the models which are within $95\%$ confidence interval. Could anyone tell me how I can define the confidence interval for the reduced chi-square? And also what is the limit of reduced chi-square value to find the best model? And please share any literature related with reduced ch-square test.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Confidence intervals (CIs) usually refer to parameters of distributions. The only parameter of $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu)$ is its degrees of freedom $\nu,$ which presumably you know. So can you explain what your CI refers to and what you are going to use it for? // If you have $Q \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(10),$ then $P(3.247 < Q \le  20.483) \approx 0.95,$ but that isn't properly called a CI, In R statistical software `qchisq(c(.025,.975),10)` returns quantiles 3.246973 and 20.483177. Dividing by df, that's 0.3247 and 2.0483. Also $P(Q \le 10) =  P(Q/\nu \le 1) = 0.5595.$

Comment: Also, can you explain how you evaluate or estimate $\sigma$ and degrees of freedom $\nu$ in your application? I checked your similar (unanswered / uncommented) Question on stat.stackexchange. You were right to try that site first, But you need to tell all of us more about your data, computations, and objectives before we can have any idea how to help. If you can supply details, I suggest you edit both of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am not a statistician, and I could be wrong with notations and definitions. I just share some of my thoughts because I also came across this problem occasionally.

In some scenarios we calculate the reduced chi square for a "goodness of fit" rather than "minimizing chi square for best-fit parameters", and we want to exclude those fit with reduced chi square greater than some "chi_cut value". We hope there is a relation between this "chi_cut value" and the probability of reduced chi square < "chi_cut value". To find such a relation, we may need to go back to the mathematical basis of doing such a "goodness of fit" test.

There is an assumption (usually not a big one) here for this reduced chi square test: the measurement errors $\sigma$ are Gaussian. Then we can compute the likelihood of the fit by

$P = a\cdot \Pi_i \cdot \exp (- \frac{(obs_i-model)^2}{\sigma_i^2}) = a\cdot \exp{(-\Sigma_i \frac{(obs_i-model)^2}{\sigma_i^2})} = a\cdot \exp (-\nu \cdot\chi_\nu^2)$, ... ... (1)

where $a$ is some normalizing constant. In case of optimizing parameters, we want $P$ to be maximized and thus $\Sigma_i \frac{(obs_i-model)^2}{\sigma_i^2}$ minimized. In case of find the relation between "chi_cut value" and the probability, we can simply use Equation (1): Assuming $\sigma_i$ is reasonably measured, then roughly $\chi_\nu^2 = 1$ and $P_0 = a\cdot\exp (-\nu)$. If somehow we find $\chi_\nu^2 = 4$ in a fit, then $P_1 = a\cdot \exp (-4\nu)$. It seems reasonable to me to ignore the factor $\nu$ here, and define $P_0$ is the case where the model is good enough at the measurement noise of $\sigma_i$, while $P_1$ is the case where observations deviate $2\sigma$ from model. Similarly, $\chi_\nu^2 = 9$ means observations deviate $3\sigma$ from model, and so on. So, I'd prefer to use this "chi_cut value" vs "$n$ sigma" relation, $\chi_\nu^2 = n^2$, instead of calculating the probability $P$ where $\nu$ is involved. Personally I would rejected those with $\chi_\nu^2 > 4$ or $\chi_\nu^2 > 9$.